# query bokeh multi_line with markers

Tags: python, bokeh, multiline

I would like to know if there is a way to add markers to multiline for bokeh. I can get the multiple lines but then p.circle() doesn't seem to work on list of lists. Here is a sample:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6, Spectral11

numlines = 2
mypalette = Spectral6[0:numlines]

data = {'x_values': [[1, 2, 3], [1,2,3]],
        'y_values': [[1, 2, 3], [4 ,5, 6]], 'labels': ['a', 'b'], 'line_color': mypalette}
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure()
p.multi_line(xs='x_values', ys='y_values', line_color='line_color', source=source)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0` there is not. You would need to call `p.circle`, `p.square`, etc. for each "sub" line in the multi-line.

Comment: oh too bad. Thanks anyway